# Average engagement time per session different in GA4 and BigQuery for screens

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

Here is my code to calculate monthly "average engagement time per session" for screens in BigQuery:

```
select 

DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE from TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)), month) as trunc_month,

params1.value.string_value AS screen_name,

avg(params2.value.int_value/60000) as avg_engagement_time_min,

FROM
      `table_name` as base, unnest(event_params) as params1 , unnest(event_params) as params2 
      where event_name = 'user_engagement'
      and params1.key='firebase_screen'
      and params2.key='engagement_time_msec'


AND FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', DATE_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp), month)) BETWEEN @DS_START_DATE AND @DS_END_DATE

group by 1,2
order by 1,avg_engagement_time_min desc
```

The resulting figures are quite different from GA4 results. For example, for a particular screen in November, GA4 is showing 49 seconds as the "Average engagement time per session" when I select a date range of 1 Nov to 30th Nov, and bigquery is showing 4.73 minutes for November.

Answer (score 0):

Engagement time data is sent multiple times in each session, and your query was averaging all of them, which is not the correct approach. To address this issue , you should consider using the maximum engagement time value for each session and then calculate the average. look at this :

```
WITH session_engagement AS (
  SELECT
    user_pseudo_id,
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS session_id,
    MAX((SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'session_engaged')) AS session_engaged,
    MAX((SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'engagement_time_msec')) AS engagement_time_msec
  FROM
    `table_name`
  WHERE
    event_name = 'user_engagement'
    AND FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', DATE_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp), month)) BETWEEN @DS_START_DATE AND @DS_END_DATE
  GROUP BY
    user_pseudo_id,
    session_id
)

SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)), month) AS trunc_month,
  params1.value.string_value AS screen_name,
  AVG(session_engagement.engagement_time_msec / 60000) AS avg_engagement_time_min
FROM
  `table_name` AS base,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS params1,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS params2
LEFT JOIN
  session_engagement
  ON base.user_pseudo_id = session_engagement.user_pseudo_id
  AND (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(base.event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') = session_engagement.session_id
WHERE
  event_name = 'user_engagement'
  AND params1.key = 'firebase_screen'
  AND params2.key = 'engagement_time_msec'
  AND FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', DATE_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp), month)) BETWEEN @DS_START_DATE AND @DS_END_DATE
GROUP BY
  1, 2
ORDER BY
  1, avg_engagement_time_min DESC
```

Comment: thanks for sharing, but the difference is now even higher than before!